# What's the word equivalent to, "Announcement! Announcement!" or "Attention! Attention!"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, oral, phrase

In the French speaking parts of Switzerland, when an announcement comes on the speaker says something like:

> cir-key-ont, cir-key-on (in my best phonetical spelling possible)

Seems like there is a clear "t" on the end of the first phrase but it isn't pronounced on the second one.

I tried using French dictation on my device and it wrote

> ce qui ont ce qu'ils ont

Which is obviously not what I'm looking for and clearly I cannot imitate the phrase for the life of me.

Ideas?

Answer (score 17):

That's certainly:

> *Chères clientes, chers clients !* (Dear customers)

The expression is not specific to Switzerland.

Comment: It seems the same message is also played on public transportation. It's okay to call transport riders customers?

Comment: Sure, they pay for it.

Comment: Impressed by your phonetic reading skills, +1!

Answer (score 0):

The expression would work out as

> *Mesdames et messieurs !*

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE.  This is another way to make an announcement, but it does not correspond to what the OP heard.